# converting from yolov4 or yolov5 to coreml

Tags: yolo, coreml, onnx-coreml

What is the typical process to convert a yolov4 or yolov5 model to coreml. I see things like Pytorch to Onnx to CoreML. I am using turicreate and stuck in yolov2 land. Has anyone tried this on v4 or v5?

Comment: also stuck here... I could convert to .h5 but facing a tons of issues converting to coreml. could you convert yolov2 successfully to coreml?

Comment: I use Turicreate which trains a yolov2 model and generates a coreml model, but we are up to yolov5 now. Turicreate seems  likes it dead in terms of new features or new model support. So I guess we need to figure out how to port higher yolo models to coreml..

Comment: this doc I guess we could use coreml tools https://coremltools.readme.io/docs

Comment: yes you can try training in tensorflow,keras or pytorch and then convert it.
but it seems not so easy.
or you can ask them, they have a convert pipline for v3 and v4 and (v5) but not so cheap:
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

Comment: Yes we figured out the steps to make it work. This ultralytics I realize they left out a bunch of steps. Kind of shady in my view. Now we are trying to figure out how to change the swift framework we had in yolov2 to work in yolov5. once I have that worked out I will post the full solution.

Comment: ah cool, so you could convert v4/v5 to coreml? which way did you choose?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a YOLOv5 model into CoreML format:

```
python export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --include coreml
```